# Mysql block auto indexes

Tags: mysql

i don't understand however, mysql create auto index alot of. 
create same index between of 60-70 items.
and not auto delete these indexes

all of them included same columns.

[image]

do you have any idea ? because, mysql very slow response when created this indexes.
why mysql need create this indexes i don't know ?

how can i block create indexes ? or how can i find why created this indexes ?

Thanks

Comment: The only indexes that are created automatically are for foreign keys. Show the output of `show create table yourTable`

Comment: I don't think MySQL creates an index by itself, are you sure you are not doing it somehow yourself?

Comment: UNIQUE KEY `TARIH_44` (`TARIH`,`KAD`,`MAK`,`APP`),
  UNIQUE KEY `TARIH_45` (`TARIH`,`KAD`,`MAK`,`APP`),
....  i don't run any create index query. but maybe my some queries create index

Comment: is it caused by this query;  "REPLACE INTO table (TARIH,SAAT,KAD,MAK,APP,ZAMAN,FUNC) VALUES ... "